# How good is the pseudo-radom-sequence assuming the truth of RH?

Tags: cryptography, riemann-hypothesis, mobius-function

The Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to the claim that the sequence of
moebius-values (numbers not being squarefree are skipped) behave similar to a random walk.

Let's assume that the Riemann hypothesis is true.

My question :

> Is this sequence a good pseudo-random-sequence exhibitting good randomness ? Or do we just have equally often the signs $-1$ and $1$ in the long run ?

I experimented with the moebius-function and got very good results.

Motivation : Since pseudo-random-sequences are very useful for crytographical purposes, the Riemann-hypothesis would become even more important, if the answer to my question would be yes.

But I have doubts whether the indepence of the bits is implied by the Riemann-hypothesis.